# Can't import video to my Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If anyone has a clue, please feel free to tell me.

1. I imported an MP4 video into the assets folder
2. Drag and drop the video into StreamingAssets folder
3. Apply the quality form 0.5 to 1 of  video
4. Error message displayed on console:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MovieImporter' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object."

5. The video can't be played in the iOS and Android application while application was exported successfully.
6. Other video can played normally as imported before.

**Other Situation (same error still occur):**

1. I tried to updated latest Unity version and reboot computer serveral times.
2. I tried to open a new project to import video into StreamingAssets folder.
3. I tried to press "Reimport all", the full project can't played video normally.
4. I tried to use Windows 7 to import assets.
5. I tired to copy a GameObject to played video which are imported before and played normally,

but new GameObject can't played video normally, old GameObject still function normally,
same error message displayed :

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed.

Platform:

- Uniy Plus Subscrible, Unity 5.4.2f2, Mac OS Sierra
- VideoPlaybackBehaviour(Vuforia)

Comment: Please include your code. Without it, we can't tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: TIP: Never write URGENT

Comment: Essentially the MovieImporter object has been disposed- track that in your code

Comment: yeap, urgent is a tag that is not going to improve any result...

Comment: Are you sure your video is converted to OGG file format (on Windows QuickTIme is required) ? Otherwise you can convert it yourself ahead.

Comment: @Programmer https://github.com/thirunar/unityvuforiaplayback/blob/master/Assets/Vuforia%20Video%20Playback/Scripts/VideoPlaybackBehaviour.cs

Comment: @JeremyThompson Sorry, and thank you.

Comment: @JeremyThompson The MovieImporter is Unity scripting API - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieImporter.html

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Great, thank you!

Comment: @Kardux I use mp4 format, but old object can play a video, and new object cant play the same video. Very strange.